# Buscar valor desde un input button sin recargar pagina

Tags: php

Cargo una tabla con registros provenientes de una consulta Oracle. En cada fila sitúo 1 botón, al presionarlo necesito llamar una funcion PHP que me traiga el contenido en forma modal o en un div al frente(es solo texto), y que tenga un botón para cerrarlo. La funcion hace una consulta por el campo NUMERO_SOCIO , que ya lo tengo disponible.
No se como vincular el valor de NUMERO_SOCIO con cada fila de la tabla y como usar el evento Onclick para hacer la consulta y que la muestre.
Ayuda ?
El código vinculado :

```html
while ($fila = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    $vsocio=trim($fila['NUM_SOCIO']);
    $vfecha=trim($fila['FECHA_HORA']);
    $vapellido=trim($fila['APELLIDO']);
    $vnombre=trim($fila['NOMBRE']);
            
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "    <td align='center'>" . $vsocio . "</td>\n";
    echo "    <td align='right'>" . $vfecha . "</td>\n";
    echo "    <td align='left'>" . substr($vnombre . ", " . $vapellido,0,30) . "</td>\n";
    echo "    <td align='center'><input type='button' value='Ver' onClick=''></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Podrías hacer que en el onClick se llame una función, q reciba como parametro el nro del socio. En esa función se trae lo q pides y se muestra en una modal. No se si es la idea q tienes o entendi mal

Comment: Como dice @manucoBianco, el evento onClick tendría que recibir como parámetro el número de socio, y luego abrir el modal. Para todo esto necesitarías trabajar con JavaScript en vez de PHP, ya que no quieres recargar la página.

Comment: No he podido resolverlo, agradezco igual tu ayuda , he hecho cambios en el código para hacerlo más sencillo, tratare de cerrar este hilo para publicar el nuevo.

Comment: Hola, al parecer no está muy bien planteada tu pregunta, ya que dejas algunas dudas sobre lo que requieres, lo que dice @alanfcm está perfecto, conforme a lo que comentas en tu pregunta, ahora bien, si lo que necesitas es mediante el número de socio ejecutar una consulta y lo que te arroja la consulta mostrarlo en una ventana modal, tendrías que usar algo como Ajax para para no tener que recargar todo la página, pero no queda de todo claro sí eso es lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es simplemente ver la fila en un modal, yo agregaria una clase al boton y escucharia por el evento click.  Luego, agarraria el contenido de la fila y lo despelgaria en el modal.  Algo asi:

```js
$(".ver").on("click", function() {
  var tds = $(this).parent().siblings();
  var content = "";
  $.each(tds, function(i, td) {
    content += $(td).text() + "<br>";
  });
  
  $("#myModal .modal-body").html(content);
  $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tbody
<tr>
    <td align='center'>socio1</td>
    <td align='right'>8/2/2018</td>
    <td align='left'>Juan Perez</td>
    <td align='center'><input type='button' value='Ver' class="ver"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='center'>socio2</td>
    <td align='right'>8/3/2018</td>
    <td align='left'>John Smith</td>
    <td align='center'><input type='button' value='Ver' class="ver"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenisimo, ire probando. La idea concreta es que al hacer click en el boton , este ya tenga cargado de algun modo el NUMERO_SOCIO , y ejecute una funcion con la consulta a la base. No estoy viendo como asocio el botón al valor del campo NUMERO_SOCIO de cada fila que cargo a la tabla .. pero calculo sera cosa de verlo mejor . Lo que necesito mostrar son comentarios de texto ( 1 solo campo varchar ) viculados a ese socio, para mostrarlo en modal y poder cerrar con un boton.

Comment: Hola , cuando hago el bucle y cargo cada fila de la tabla, como asigno la variable $vsocio a cada fila ?

Comment: Asi como lo tienes esta bien.  Podrias agregar un input tipo hidden y alli guardar el numero_socio.  De esa forma lo podrias leer asi como yo lo hice.

Comment: no he podido , como seria ?

Comment: No entiendo bien que es lo que quieres hacer.  El campo que necesitas es NUM_SOCIO, que seria el primer valor de cada fila?

Comment: Si, cargo una tabla con los registros de una consulta , necesito que en la ultima columna de cada fila haya un button , al presionarlo necesito llamar a una funcion ( que esta en otro archivo que llamo funciones.php ) para que me traiga el contenido de un campo de texto  vinculado a ese NUMERO_SOCIO.

Comment: Por un lado necesito saber como levantar el valor NUMERO_SOCIO de la fila donde hago click en el boton, y lo segundo sería de que modo llamo a la funcion para que me retorne la consulta, y la presente en un modal .

Comment: Tendrias que usar Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice Victoria Ruiz. el evento onClick tendría que recibir como parámetro el número de socio, y luego abrir el modal. Para todo esto necesitarías trabajar con JavaScript en vez de PHP, ya que no quieres recargar la página.

si es eso lo que necesitas solo deberás agregar al botón del evento la Función **OnClientClick="return comprueba();"** 
y añadir esta etiqueta antes esta etiqueta de **JavaScript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 funtion comprueba(){
return confirm("Confirme el Postback");
}
</script>
```

ese evento es del cliente y al retornar false evitaras el postback pero no podrias usar el evento en el servidor OnClick si no hasta que des aceptar.
Espero te sirva Saludos